# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar - error in 2 basic arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm a new learner, and I am learning based on some videos. In the video the code faced no problem. However, I faced with a Traceback. I can't figure out what the problem is.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
arr_bis = np.array ([[1,2,3],[7,1,6],[9,6,3]])
arr1 = arr_bis[:,1]
arr2 = arr_bis[:,2]
print (f"ARR1{arr1}")
print (f"ARR2{arr2}")
print (np.concatenate(arr1, arr2), axis = 0)
```

I want to concatenate two arrays.
This is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 7, in 
File "<**array_function** internals>", line 180, in concatenate
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

> > > 

Can somebody tell me what is the problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a parenthesis in your print.

```
print (np.concatenate(arr1, arr2), axis = 0)
```

should be

```
print (np.concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) incorrectly.

The first parameter should be an iterable of the arrays to concatenate

> numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None, dtype=None, casting="same_kind")

```
np.concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=0)
```

output: `array([2, 1, 6, 3, 6, 3])`

In your case, not only you passed arr2 as the second parameter, but you also passed the `axis=0` parameter to the wrong function (here to `print`):

```
print(                             # print function
      np.concatenate(arr1, arr2),  # first parameter of print
                                   # with incorrect calling
      axis = 0                     # second (invalid) parameter of print
)
```